# Flutter - Filter element with same name in array

Tags: arrays, flutter

I have a arrays with multiple elements, some of this elements has same name and repeat through array. I need to get all elements of this array, getting only one elements of repeated elements and all non repeated elements.

I read [this document](https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2) about arrays in dart but doesn´t much helpier. I don't have example code, i don´t know how exactly that i start.

Do, anybody know how can i do this?

**EDIT: ARRAY EXAMPLE**

Many mistakes in JSON, forget it, is a simple example.

```
[{'id': '19', fabricante: 'AA', modelo: 'h4000 DN100', 'configuracionRaw': 'CC', 'configuracion': {'emisor': '4', 'pw': '10.0', 'valorMomento': 'null', 'valorMaximo': '9999999.0', 'dataloggerPeriodoMin': '60', 'dataloggerHora': '08:00','fw': 'null','dataloggerPeriodoFTP': '1', 'dataloggerHoraFTP': '10', 'contadorParado': '240', 'alarmaPeriodo':'3', 'alarmaUmbral': '1000', 'alarmaEspontaneo': 'true'}, {'id': '20', fabricante: 'AA', modelo: 'h4000 DN100', 'configuracionRaw': 'CC', 'configuracion': {'emisor': '4', 'pw': '10.0', 'valorMomento': 'null', 'valorMaximo': '9999999.0', 'dataloggerPeriodoMin': '60', 'dataloggerHora': '08:00','fw': 'null','dataloggerPeriodoFTP': '1', 'dataloggerHoraFTP': '10', 'contadorParado': '240', 'alarmaPeriodo':'3', 'alarmaUmbral': '1000', 'alarmaEspontaneo': 'true'}} ]
```

**CODE EXAMPLE**

DataMaker is a array of data.

```
dataMaker.forEach((val) {
  print(val['fabricante']); //RETURN NAME
    if(filteredList!=val['fabricante']()){ //ERROR
    filteredList.add(val);
    }
  });
```

Comment: can you share your code it would be more helpful to solve the issue

Comment: Array of what kind of elements? just Strings ? Objects ? at least provide and example of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may look a bit primitive, but works as expected

```
List list = [2, 5, 7, 9, 22, 2, 7, 5, 9, 22, 6, 4, 7, 9, 2];
List nonRepetitive = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  bool repeated = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < nonRepetitive.length; j++) {
    if (list[i] == nonRepetitive[j]) {
      repeated = true;
    }
  }
  if (!repeated) {
    nonRepetitive.add(list[i]);
  }
}
print(nonRepetitive);
```

This returns

```
[2, 5, 7, 9, 22, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via `Set`

```
final newList = myList.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: This solution won't work on custom objects. On custom objects you have to override ```==``` & ```hasCode```.

Answer (score 0):

why not using a `Set`

```
void main() { 
   Set numberSet = new  Set(); 
   numberSet.add(20); 
   numberSet.add(20); 
   numberSet.add(5); 
   numberSet.add(60); 
   numberSet.add(70);


   for(var no in numberSet) { 
      print(no); 
   } 
}
```

and this will print the following

```
20
5
60
70
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get an array of unique elements you can use 'set' or 'foreach'

working dartpad https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0a76f6dfe66a40b5e3f09ce74a739fe1

method 1

```
void main() {
  List list = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6];
  print(list.toSet().toList());
}

// answer
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

method 2

```
void main() {
List list = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6];
List filteredList = [];
list.forEach((val) {
    if(filteredList.indexOf(val) == -1){
    filteredList.add(val);
    }
  });
  print(filteredList);
}

// answer
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in several ways, one can be using **Array.fold**, e.g.

```
var withNoDuplications = yourArray.fold([], (current, next) {
     var elementExist = current.firstWhere((element) {
      return element['id'] == next['id'];
    }, orElse: () => null);

    if(elementExist == null) {
      current.add(next);
    }    
    return current;
  });
print(withNoDuplications);
```

Another solution more elaborated would be using **Classes**, for that you would need first to convert your JSON into regular classes using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) for example, and overriding the **==** double equal operator. e.g.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  Person({this.name, this.age});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name $age';
  }

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);

  bool operator ==(o) => o is Person && name == o.name && age == o.age;
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode + age.hashCode; //use a more reliable hashCode
}
```

This way you can use **toSet** as mentioned in previous answers.

```
List list = [Person(), Person(), Person()];
var result = list.toSet().toList()
```

Second option is more elaborated but I think it's more maintainable in the long run.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Hosar,Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

I didn't need @json_serializable for just toSet() support, though I did have to add @override decorators/annotations.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  Person({this.name, this.age});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name $age';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(o) => o is Person && name == o.name && age == o.age;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode + age.hashCode; //use a more reliable hashCode
}
```